# how to add comment before begin statement in sqlalchemy for postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

in sqlalchemy, we start a transaction by doing

```py
with conn.begin():
  ...
```

this will issue a `BEGIN` to database
I'm wondering how I can add comment to it, like sending `/* comment */ BEGIN`
there is a begin event https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.begin but I can't see how to add comment in it.

this would help instructing transaction behaviour using comment, like sharding in pgcat.